# Basic Lag TS Object in R not "working"

Tags: r, time-series

Here is some basic info about my data

```
> prod.ts
Time Series:
Start = 2009.26027397260 
End = 2010.83719704953 
Frequency = 52 
 [1]  895 1780 1989 1996 1660 1860 1921 2188 1789 1996 2085 2185 2205 2232 2062
[16] 2257 2000 2055 2084 1977 2051 1999 2428 2220 2385 2174 2307 2549 2211 2224
[31] 1922 2091 2318 1986 2080 2069 2106 1998 1480 1841 1819 2119 2109 2072 2206
[46] 1965 2017 2296 1866 2262 2088 2157 2582 2398 2325 1393 2577 2375 2452 2534
[61] 2586 2032 2781 2423 2575 2362 2132 2375 2105 2425 2346 2495 2908 2301 2918
[76] 2426 2633 2312 2472 2305 2622 2662 2626
```

I am stumped as to why these two are equivlane

```
> length(prod.ts)
[1] 83
> length(lag(prod.ts, 1))
[1] 83
```

This probably shows that I am new to R and Time series, but what am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lag.ts` lags the time index.  The data is unchanged.  Compare the series `g` and `lag(g)` below.  Note that the data is the same but `g` goes from 1 to 5 and `lag(g)` goes from 0 to 4:

```
> g <- ts(101:105)
> g
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 5 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 101 102 103 104 105
> lag(g)
Time Series:
Start = 0 
End = 4 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 101 102 103 104 105
```

Answer (score 6):

That is just the way `lag()` for `ts` objects is defined. From `help(lag)`:

> ```
> lag                   package:stats                    R
> Documentation
>
> Lag a Time Series
>
> Description:
>
>      Compute a lagged version of a time series, shifting the time base
>      back by a given number of observations.
> ```

Use `xts()` or `zoo()` if you'd rather have NAs added while keeping start and end times.